# Hide/Show bar in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I add a bar that appears and reappears at the top of a page, something like the one for the adobe reader app?
I have checked other peoples post but all i see is posts about the application bar, and i dont think this can be put on top of a page

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in control for that in WP7 SDK. You may try search for it in other libraries but I think you should just create it by your own (using standard grid/panel items).

If you'd like to show it when standard `ApplicationBar` is expanded you should subscribe to [`StateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.statechanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event on `ApplicationBar` and show/hide your own bar on top.